# What order does McCree shoot enemies in when he ults?

Tags: overwatch

So. A McCree manages to get line of sight on 6 players who all happen to have their sound turned off at the same time. What order do they get punished in? The first that came into McCree's line of sight? The one with the highest high noon charge? From left to right? Random?

Comment: It took me a minute to realize that "6 players who all happen to have their sound turned off" was a joke and not actually a serious part of your question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

McCree fires right to left, *always*. It does not matter if you acquire more right targets after your left-er targets. It also does not matter which shots will result in kills -- right to left, *always*.

This can be verified for yourself in the Practice Range, where there are 2 Training Bots next to each other.

Comment: Unrelated but mildly disturbing - the Training bots yell "Ow!" when shot at.

Comment: That video shows him shooting right to left several times. It doesn't go anywhere near showing that he does that always in all situations, even with new targets entering the area. I imagine you're right, you're just overstating the evidence a bit.

Comment: @DCShannon Are you comparing the footage at :51 to the footage at 1:09? At :51, McCree turns right to left, acquires 3 targets (right to left, while turning), then fires. At 1:09, McCree again acquires 3 targets, right-left-right, as they run out onto the bridge, and he once again fires right to left -- *different* than the "Target Acquired" order.

Comment: It's not super clear to me if some of those targets in the later instance were not initially seen. All their names are showing up at the start already. I also don't see an example where they cross paths. What's this "right-left-right" you're referring to?

Comment: @DCShannon At the start of the clip, Pharah runs out onto the bridge (from the right), a fraction of a second later, Reaper runs out onto the bridge (from the left), finally, widowmaker runs out onto the bridge (again from the right). Targets aren't acquired unless the targeting circle appears around them; the names being visible have nothing to do with valid targeting for his ult.